# How to manipulate the calculation of percentage in summary table?

Tags: r

In the data below, I have 7 patients who have undergone surgeries for muliple indications, two of the patients have undergone surgery on the same day for two different reasons. When I try to summaries this data using tbl_summary function, it shows total number of observations as 9 (indications for surgeries), and it calculates the percentage considering the denominator i.e., 9. How do I manipulate the denominator to total number of unique participant.index, i.e., 7 when calculating the percentage? Do we have an option in gt_summary or any others? Thank you.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(gtsummary)

participant.index = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7)
repeat.instance = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
indication.surgery = c(
  "ibs",
  "infection",
  "infection",
  "renalstones",
  "ibs",
  "infection",
  "infection",
  "ibs",
  "tumour"
)
date.surgery = c(
  "2019-01-10",
  "2019-01-01",
  "2018-01-01",
  "2018-01-01",
  "2017-09-10",
  "2000-09-09",
  "2015-01-10",
  "2015-01-10",
  "2006-09-09"
)
mydata = data.table(participant.index,
                    repeat.instance,
                    indication.surgery,
                    date.surgery)

mydata %>%
  select(indication.surgery, participant.index) %>%
  tbl_summary (
    label = list (indication.surgery ~ "Indications"),
    statistic = list(
      all_categorical() ~ "{n}/{length(unique(mydata $ participant.index))}, ({p}%)"
    ),
    missing_text = "(Missing Observations)",
    percent = c("cell")
  ) %>%
  
  modify_table_styling(spanning_header =  "Indications") %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Indication for Surgery**") %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "Number of observations, Frequency (%)")
```

Comment: `Error: unexpected ',' in:
"label = list(indication.surgery ~
                 "Indication for Surgery"),"`

Comment: I have rectified the error, a parenthesis was missing. Could you guys please let me know how do I resolve this problem. I have multiple data.tables that need this types of analysis. Thanks.

Comment: If your constaint in this problem is that you use pkg:gtsummary, then it looks to me that you should be using `tbl_custom_summary` rather than the more restrictive `tbl_summary` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know how do I do that?

Comment: could someone please help me with this? thank you.

Comment: Did you try using tbl_custom_summary?